# How would the intersection of two uncountable sets form a countably infinite set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This is based off my last question [How would the intersection of two uncountable sets be finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112493/how-would-the-intersection-of-two-uncountable-sets-be-finite)

Here is the problem(from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications)
[image]

The book's definition on countable
[image]

And the definition of having the same cardinality
[image]

I was able to get 11c pretty easily. What I thought was the intersection of the same uncountable set, say [1,2], that is [1,2]∩[1,2] would be [1,2], a uncountable set. Via help, I was able to get understand 11a. That is if you have two uncountable sets, say
(−∞,0]∩[0,∞), the intersection of those two sets would be that one value, zero, meaning it is finite countable. What I am struggling with is applying that same idea to 11b. What I thought of was having two intervals that didn't end quite at the same spot say (−∞,3]∩[0,∞) but the intersection of those would be [0, 3] which itself is a uncountable set. From 11a, what endpoints would you set on the intervals so that A ∩ B would be countably infinite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about $[0, 1] \bigcup \{2, 3, 4, 5, \dots \}$ and $[5, 6] \bigcup \{7, 8, 9, 10, \dots\}$?

Comment: {2,3,4,5,…} is countable though isn't it?

Comment: @committedandroider Yes, but when you union it with $[0,1]$ the set becomes uncountable.

Comment: but the question is the union of two uncountable sets, not one uncountable and the other countable

Comment: @Bonehead Let $A = [0, 2] \cup \{2, 3, 4, 5, \dots\}$ and $B = [5, 6] \cup \{7, 8, 9, 10, \dots\}$. Then $A$ and $B$ are uncountable and $A \cap B = \{5, 6, 7, 8, \dots\}$ is countably infinite.

Comment: @committedandroider Let $A=[0,1]\cup \{2,3,4,\ldots\}$ and $B=[5,6]\cup \{7,8,9,\ldots\}$.  Then both $A$ and $B$ are uncountable, but the intersection $A\cap B$ is countable.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Funny how we both wrote almost exactly the same sentence!

Comment: @OohAah When I submitted my comment, I thought, for a second, that I somehow submitted it twice.

Comment: Ahh i get it thanks guys!! Tricky problem. But @0ahAah, are you actually Gina G?

Comment: Yes. I have now retired from music industry and I am trying to learn some math these days.

Comment: @OohAah , to represent {2,3,4,5} in set builder notation, would you do     {x \in\ Z | x >= 2} ?

Comment: You should write {x \in \Z | 2 <= x <= 5}.

Comment: but if you were to follow that pattern and do {y \in\ Y| 7 <= y <= 10}, wouldn't you get the empty set for the intersection?

Comment: Oh I see. You want to write $\{2, 3, 4, 5, \dots\}$ as $\{x \in \mathbb{Z} : x \geq 2\}$. That was correct. I thought you wanted to write $\{2, 3, 4, 5\}$ which is finite without the dots.

Answer (score 4):

$$
A = \bigcup_{\text{even }n} [n,n+1],\qquad B = \bigcup_{\text{odd }n} [n,n+1]
$$
The intersection is the set of all integers.

Comment: but the set of even integers is countably infinite?

Comment: Correct.  The set of _all_ integers is the intersection $A\cap B$ and that set is countably infinite.  Both of the sets $A$ and $B$ are uncountable. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: yeah thank you for clarifying that. I didn't see that

Answer (score 0):

let A and B be two uncountable sets . (to show AUB is uncountable ) 
obviously A is contained in AUB as well B is contained in AUB .
since A is an uncountable set and then AUB being the superset of an uncountable set ,is itself uncountable . we are done